# Proof with integral properties

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to explain/looking for an answer whether a positive function $u=f(t)$ exists, for which $\int_{t=0}^{1}u\,dt = \int_{t=1}^{0}u\,dt$ is true.

As we all know, the correct theorem is $\int_{t=0}^{1}u\,dt = - \int_{t=1}^{0}u\,dt$. But in our case when I reverse the integral from $\int_{t=1}^{0}u\,dt$ to $-\int_{t=0}^{1}u\,dt$ then both integrals aren't equal. I have no clue to support my answer.

Comment: It looks like you showed that such a function $u$ does not exist.

Comment: Assume this is true, then $\int_{t=0}^1 2u =0$. For nonnegative $u$ this is only true if $u=0$. Thus you find a contradicition

Comment: Don't exactly know what kind of answer my professor expects. But yes, it looks contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Riemann integral $\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm dx$ is defined for $a<b$, but there is a *useful convention* to say that $\int_b^a f(x)\mathrm dx = -\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm dx$ which is in fact the *definition* of $\int_b^a f(x)\mathrm dx$ for $a<b$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes, it's true for the standard Riemann integral. My question looks contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{t=0}^{1}u\,dt = \int_{t=1}^{0}u\,dt$

$\Leftrightarrow \int_{t=0}^{1}u\,dt - \int_{t=1}^{0}u\,dt = 0$

$\Leftrightarrow \int_{t=0}^{1}u\,dt + \int_{t=0}^{1}u\,dt = 0$

$\Leftrightarrow \int_{t=0}^{1}u\,dt = 0$

As we have $\forall x \in [0,1]$, $u(x) \geq 0$, this is only possible if $\{ x \in [0,1] / u(x) \neq 0 \}$ is countable.

For instance: $\forall x \in [0,1] \setminus \{\frac{1}{2}\}, u(x) = 0$ and $u(\frac{1}{2}) = 1$

Comment: thanks for your answer.
First, I also got the first two steps but wasn't sure. But why is $\int_{t=0}^{1} u\,dt+\int_{t=0}^{1} u\,dt$ equivalent to only $\int_{t=0}^{1} u\,dt$ and not $2\int_{t=0}^{1} u\,dt$?

Comment: @studyhenry I shortcuted: 2 times 0 is 0 :)